# Is every map between connected CW-complexes homotopic to a map sending $x$ to $y$?

Tags: homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a continuous map between connected CW-complexes $X$ and $Y$.

Choose points $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Is $f$ homotopic to a map sending $x$ to $y$?

Comment: Do you have any results at your disposal that you think might help? As written, this just looks like a homework problem. Please provide some context.

Comment: I'm reading this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2480.pdf) on aspherical manifolds where the statement is used implicitely after Theorem 1.1. Sadly, I do not know much techniques about CW-complexes.

Comment: Good to know. Just so you know, these kinds of things should be included in the question otherwise the question may be closed for lacking context.

Comment: Here's a necessary condition: $f(x)$ and $y$ must be in the same path component

Comment: @AlexG. Note that $Y$ is path-connected as a connected CW-complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Suppose $f: X\to Y$ is any map with $f(x) = y^{\prime}$ and let $\gamma:[0,1]\to Y$ be a path between $\gamma(0)=y^{\prime}$ and $\gamma(1)=y$. Then $f$ and $\gamma$ together constitute a continuous map $$X\times [0,1]\supset X\times\{0\}\cup_{\{x\}\times \{0\}} \{x\}\times [0,1]\to Y.$$
Since the inclusion $\{x\}\hookrightarrow X$ is a *cofibration*, this map extends to a map $X\times [0,1]\to Y$, which can be interpreted as a homotopy from $f$ to a map $X\to Y$ sending $x$ to $y$.

More details: First, without loss of generality, we can assume that $x$ is a $0$-cell of the given CW-structure by potentially passing to a subdivision. It is therefore sufficient to show that the any inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$ of a subcomplex $A$ of a CW-complex $X$ is a cofibration. The corresponding extension problem 
$$(\ddagger)\qquad X\times [0,1]\supset X\times\{0\}\cup_{A\times \{0\}} A\times [0,1]\to Y$$ can then inductively be reduced to the special case $X={\mathbb D}^n\supset A={\mathbb S}^{n-1}$, where it holds since the inclusion on the LHS of $(\ddagger)$ is a deformation retract.

*Reference:* Hatcher, [Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), Proposition 0.16

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true and to prove this, just follow the proof of the [Cellular approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem).